# Python update a field in a json file

Tags: python, json

### Here is my code and the json file look like

```
import numpy as np
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime 


r = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/news?category=general&token=')
with open('json_response.json', 'w') as fd:
    json.dump(r.json(), fd, indent=4)

with open('json_response.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for news in data:
        print(datetime.fromtimestamp(news['datetime']))

#   Update Unix datetime to readable datetime and write to file
```

This is how my json file look like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZUMm.jpg

What I want is to update the whole file 'datetime' field. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: So you want to update every datetime field within the whole json file?

Comment: Yes, and sorry for my bad English, I may not make myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the json file (dictionary) and find the time, then use the `datetime` module and convert it to something readable, and create your own string

```py
from datetime import datetime

with open('json_response.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for news in data:
        print(datetime.fromtimestamp(news['datetime']))
```

So what you have there prints a datetime object like `datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 7, 10, 29, 21)`
With that, you can access the time with attributes:

```py
> print(datetime.fromtimestamp(news['datetime']).year)
2021
```

Make a string...

```py
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(news['datetime'])
readableTimestamp = "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(timestamp.month, timestamp.day, timestamp.year)
# MONTH/DAY/YEAR (1/7/2021)
```

Put it into the dictionary and write it to the file

```py
news['datetime'] = readableTimestamp
json_file.write(news)
#OR
json.dump(news, json_file)
```

If you didn't want to read all of that or didn't understand it, here is your code

```py
with open('json_response.json', 'w+') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for news in data:
        timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(news['datetime'])
        readableTimestamp = "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(timestamp.month, timestamp.day, timestamp.year)
        news['datetime'] = readableTimestamp
    json.dump(news, json_file)
```

Comment: First, I think something could be wrong here:
json.dump(news, json_file) is out of the scope
Second, I tried the way u told but it didnt work

Comment: A. Why can’t you use json.dump? B. What do you mean didn’t work? Do you mean it errored our? If so can you send the error

Comment: A. 'news' is out of the 'for' loop. B. A is the reason. Additionally, I understood the way it works but instead of re-write the whole json file with the modified datetime, what I need is just modify the datetime field only.

Comment: I get what your saying, but you cannot just write one value, instead you have to clear the file and rewrite it again

Comment: I see, I thought of that at the beginning, but I wondered if there is any way around to do it. Anyway, I appreciate your help and your time.

Comment: If you know the byte at where the value is located you could use ‘file.seek’